# jQuery getJSON function not returning anything

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, asynchronous

I have this code:

```
$.getJSON('data.json', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

And this is the `data.json` file:

```
{
  "Sameer": {
    "Phone": "0123456789",
  },
  "Mona": {
    "Phone": "0123456789",
  },
}
```

But the `console.log(data)` not returning anything, Not even an error I don't know what is wrong with my code.

I tried to use `$.ajax()` function instead but no luck. And when I change my `data.json` file to something random like: `data.asd` I get an error that saying the file data.asd not found!

Comment: your json is not valid, it is missing enclosing [] (since it seems to be an array of objects. Try putting square brackets and try again.

Comment: @mp77 That's not true. It's has valid key/value pairs. The only syntax error is the trailing `,`

Comment: Use jsonlint.com to ensure your json is valid. It isn't valid right now..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are syntax errors on your JSON (commas), this is the right version:

```
{
  "Sameer": {
    "Phone": "0123456789"
  },
  "Mona": {
    "Phone": "0123456789"
  }
}
```

If you have silent failures, check your JSON with a tool like http://jsonlint.com/.

From [jQuery $.getJson() documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/):

> Important: As of jQuery 1.4, if the JSON file contains a syntax error,
>   the request will usually fail silently.

Comment: Thank you @LorenzoMarcon That really helped a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Correct jSon format :

```
{
    "Sameer": {
        "Phone": "0123456789"
    },
    "Mona": {
        "Phone": "0123456789"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your json has problem with `,` as `@Taki` mentioned above. I stored your corrected json at below url and there is no problem with the getJSON api. I am able to output json in console.Try running below code snippet.

```js
$.getJSON('https://api.myjson.com/bins/qnucf', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```